# Pytorch DataParallel model load with map_location

Tags: pytorch

- Model saved with

```py
net= Net()
model= torch.nn.DataParallel(net)
############################
# Training
############################

torch.save(model,'./model_shear_pre.pkl')
```

- Model loading with

```py
net = Net()
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(net, device_ids=[0,1])
model = torch.load('./model_shear_finish.pkl',  map_location={'cuda:0':'cuda:0', 'cuda:1':'cuda:0', 'cuda:2':'cuda:1', 'cuda:3':'cuda:1'})
```

---

The prob is that when training I used a machine with 4 GPU, after saving the model, I would like to test it on a new  machine with only 2 GPU.

After loading the saved model, I expect the model's `device_ids` would be `[0,1]`, but it still be `[0,1,2,3]` which is the old setting. **Is there anything wrong when saving or loading?**

Answer (score 1):

You should save the weights instead of the whole model.

```
net = Net()
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(net)
############################
# Training
############################

torch.save(model.state_dict(),'./model_shear_pre.pkl')
```

Then load the weight in CPU before move to all GPU

```
net = Net()

weights = torch.load('./model_shear_finish.pkl', map_location='cpu')
net.load_state_dict(weights)

model = torch.nn.DataParallel(net, device_ids=[0,1])
```

But if you have an already trained model that is saved using the whole model instead of just weights this might also work

```
net = torch.load('./model_shear_finish.pkl', map_location='cpu')
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(net, device_ids=[0,1])
```

I still recommend save only weights though. Saving and loading the whole model can really screw you up because you have to `import` the model the **exact same way** both in the save and load. And a lot of time that's a tricky thing to do. Like

train.py

```
from nets import Net
net = Net()
torch.save(net, './model_shear_finish.pkl')
```

inference.py

```
# this won't work
import nets
torch.load('./model_shear_finish.pkl', map_location='cpu')  

# this will work
from nets import Net
torch.load('./model_shear_finish.pkl', map_location='cpu')
```